# django-forms-builder: How do I show a completed form

Tags: django, forms

I am using `django-forms-builder`. How do i show a completed form after it has been filled out and submitted. I have a `pages` page that shows all the forms that have been created and links to the form to be filled out. I then have a `page` page which i want to be able to see all the contents thats been filled out.

`urls.py:`

```
url(r'^pages/all/$', 'myapp.views.pages', name='pages'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^forms/', include(forms_builder.forms.urls)),
```

`views.py:`

```
def pages(request):
    published = Form.objects.published()
    return render_to_response('pages.html', {'pages': Pages.objects.all(), 'published': published })

def page(request, page_id=1):
    return render_to_response('page.html', {'page': Page.objects.get(id=page_id) })
```

`pages_template.html:`

```
{% for p in pages %}
    <a href="/forms/{{p}}">{{p}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

`page_template.html`?

Comment: please give your `models.py`.

Comment: there is nothing in my models.py. Do I need to do something in there to link up the models generated in the django-form-builder app's models.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django-forms-builder, forms that have been filled out are instances of model `FormEntry`, and each individual field filled out is an instance of the model `FieldEntry`.

If you want to show a list of all forms filled out:

```
entries = FormEntry.objects.all()
```

And show them in your template.

If you want to show the contents of a filled form:

```
entry = FormEntry.objects.get(id=form_entry_id)  # you should have got the id from the listing
field_entries = FieldEntry.objects.filter(entry=entry)
```

And then show each `field_enties[i].value` in your template.

See [models.py](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/master/forms_builder/forms/models.py). In these cases, the source code is your best friend. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Really new to django so the source code of other peoples projects scare me :). This cleared things up though.